# How to map REST endpoints and their interaction within a production SPA (Angular 9.x)

Tags: angular, rest, mapping, puppeteer, dataflow

I have inherited an Angular site that has a massive custom API (over 1k endpoints) with no documentation. In order to document and understand what is happening I would like to map how the REST endpoints are called and how they respond.

I am thinking a custom script in PowerShell or Puppeteer is the way to approach this but also that there must be an Opensource tool or script already out there.

Any suggestions or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**I.** If I understand correctly your use case: **[Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)** has some features that may be useful for this purpose, especially if python is not a blocker for you. It is possible to extract a site's api with this open source framework.

(**II.** A commercial tool **[Diffbot](https://www.diffbot.com/products/automatic/)** actually does exactly what you need, you could try, the first two weeks are free trial.)